# How to auto set excel sheet's columns width in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using excel.dart package to save the data in excel.
there is an issue with auto width setting of the column

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, then found the solution.

```
Future<void> setColumnAutoFit() async {
  var excel = Excel.createExcel();
  var sheet = excel[sheetName];

  // Your logic to populate the Excel sheet goes here

  // Set auto-fit for columns
  for (var column in sheet.columns) {
    var maxLength = 0;

    for (var cell in column) {
      if (cell.value.toString().length > maxLength) {
        maxLength = cell.value.toString().length;
      }
    }

    // Set column width based on the maximum cell value length
    sheet.setColumnWidth(column.columnIndex, maxLength);
  }

  // Save the Excel file
  await excel.save(fileName);
}
```

Comment: [ChatGPT answers are strictly prohibited.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)